# Gitlab premission denied

Tags: macos, terminal, upload, gitlab

Hello i have a gitlab server and the web interface works just as ssh -T git@mijnstageportaal.nl,
but when i try to upload a folder to a blaco project its says this

```
git init
git remote add origin http://mijnstageportaal.nl/marijnboeve/sinterklaas-intocht
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
Reinitialized existing Git repository in 
/Users/marijnboeve/websites/sinterklaasintocht/.git/
fatal: remote origin already exists.
HEAD detached from v8.0.1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1. Most probably, you don't have a public key `id_rsa` at path `/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.ssh`.
   You should generate it, e.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "email@example.com"` (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/).
2. Or, repository at `http://mijnstageportaal.nl/marijnboeve/sinterklaas-intocht` really doesn't exist. You can check it with your Web client, if possible, or ask a repository owner.